# How to run the kuka_experimental program on Github in RViz?

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, kuka

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 and installed ROS Indigo in order to run the `kuka_experimental` source code which can be found on Github.

I have built the catkin workspace and compiled the `kuka_experimental` source without errors. How do I run or launch the various KUKA robot models in RViz simulation environment? Do I ROSLaunch `kuka_eki_hw_interface` or `kuka_rsi_hw_interface` or `kuka_rsi_simulator` and how do I view it in RViz?

Also how to use MoveIt with this `kuka_experimental` package as there is no Indigo version of MoveIt and Kinetic version has compile errors and requires Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Why 14.04? I'd recommend switching to Ubuntu 20.04 and ROS Noetic.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend installing a more recent version of Ubuntu (20.04 at best) and then following the ros industrial tutorials http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Tutorials or https://industrial-training-master.readthedocs.io/en/melodic/index.html. You will then need to use MoveIt Setup Assistant to create a cell based on one of the support packages in the `kuka_experimental` repository. Ideally you also read through the MoveIt tutorials. Then you can control a "simulated" kuka model in RViz.

The `eki` and `rsi` will require the respective Addons from KUKA Gmbh (EthernetKRL oder RSI) and are only required once you actually want to run the real robot.

Answer (score 0):

*Having looked into this for an hour or two, I thought that I'd post what little info I came up with.*

---

You have probably already seen and read the [kuka_experimental](http://wiki.ros.org/kuka_experimental) page on the ROS wiki site, seeing as you say that you have successfully compiled/installed the package, which is covered under section **3. Installation**.

As stated on [kuka_experimental](http://wiki.ros.org/kuka_experimental), under **4. Tutorials**

> Tutorials detailing the installation and setup of the packages will be made available at a later date.
>
> For the generic ROS-Industrial tutorials, please see the ROS-Industrial [training exercises](https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_training)

and no update has been made since 2018-03-04. Clearly, the [training exercises](https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_training) page does not offer help for the experimental release.

That said, if you look at the [Issues page](https://github.com/ros-industrial/kuka_experimental/issues) of the Github repo, in particular the [open issues related to "experimental](https://github.com/ros-industrial/kuka_experimental/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20experimental) and the [closed issues related to "experimental"](https://github.com/ros-industrial/kuka_experimental/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20experimental%20is%3Aclosed), then a few issues pop up that might be useful, such as:

- ["Jerky" motions while using kuka_rsi_hw_interface for a KUKA KR240 L210 MED #147](https://github.com/ros-industrial/kuka_experimental/issues/147)
- [kuka_experimental/kuka_eki_hw_interface in automatic mode #248](https://github.com/ros-industrial/kuka_experimental/discussions/248)
- [kuka_experimental/kuka_eki_hw_interface in automatic mode #165](https://github.com/ros-industrial/kuka_experimental/issues/165)

So this shows that you could, at least, use either `kuka_eki_hw_interface` or `kuka_rsi_hw_interface`.

Beyond that, I didn't find much more information, so maybe request that the documentation is expanded by [raising a Github issue](https://github.com/ros-industrial/kuka_experimental/issues) for more documentation or see https://github.com/ros-industrial/kuka_experimental/discussions for more specific questions.

However, at a guess, seeing as the code is *experimental*, this release is probably *only* intended for those who really know the intricacies of ROS, and who would be able to get the code up and running, unaided.

Comment: Please don't contact (or recommend contacting) maintainers directly. Instead use the respective support channels like this page here for general questions, answers.ros.org for past general questions or https://github.com/ros-industrial/kuka_experimental/discussions for more specific questions. For actual actionable issues use https://github.com/ros-industrial/kuka_experimental/issues

Comment: @SimonSchmeißer -  I have updated my answer. Please feel free to further edit my answer to remove any bad advice.